# Create parameter

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parameters

(How) Can I Sql Server create a parameter that is automatically populated from data - in other words equivalent to SAS' "Proc Sql; into:" - functionality

In SAS I can store the number of rows in a table, mytable, into a macro variable, n_rows. I am looking for something like this in sql server.

```
 proc sql noprint;


     select count(*) into :n_rows 
            from mytable

  quit;
%put &n_rows.;
```

Comment: try using UDT (user defined table types)

Comment: You need to do this on SQL Server or in SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but is this what you're looking for?

```sql
declare @numberOfRows int = (select count(*) from myTable)
select @numberOfRows
```

Comment: You are not missing something - this is exactly what I was looking for.